# How to insert my picture to google maps

Tags: javascript, image, api, maps

i need insert my map picture to my google map with markers, at sites. I have map without draggable, static zoom. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to lay an image on to google maps, in a specific location?  If so, I think this should be able to help you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: Yes, i am trying this now, but image not showing after change all gps. 
GPS i am get here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-event

Comment: Solved. Google have in first example south in top and in second is south down. lol. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-event ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: Yeah, I remember dealing with that last time I used the API.  Total nonsense.  I'm glad you were able to figure it out.